# how to selected value form ajax boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to make an option selected from the ajax value, in ajax generate true and null values, how do I make selected based on the results of ajax, here I try with the condition if else but it doesn't work

```
 if(data.otp==true){
                              console.log('this for true');
                              $("#otp").val(1);
                         }else{
                              console.log('this for null');
                              $("#otp").val(0);
                         }

   <div class="form-group row">
                  <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">OTP</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-8 select-modal">
                  <select name="otp" class="form-control" id="otp">
                        <option value="1">OTP</option>
                        <option value="0">None</option>

                      </select>
                  </div>
              </div>

 this my response data               




id: 10
client_id: 14
vendor_id: 10
name: "Bank New york"
mode: "web"
vendor_type: "bank"
status: "active"
otp: true
```

and if null

```
otp: null
```

Comment: put true in single quotes like data.otp=='true'

Comment: @AmitSingh it's not work sir, if i do that always message form log this for null

Comment: Can you share response that you get  ?

Comment: @Newbie123 Can console log are print?

Comment: I have added the response data in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value you are getting in the AJAX response. You can't get value `true` in response, it's converted to a string when you return bool in AJAX response.

You can try changing `if(data.otp==true){` to `if(data.otp=='true'){`.

Before doing above check what exactly you are getting in response.

**EDIT**:

Try changing to `if(data.otp=='true'){` to `if(data.otp){`

`If` by default handle if the value is true.

Comment: yes I have tried that, but it always issues a message in else condition

Comment: Can you post your full response data? Do console.log(data) in ajax success and paste everything here.

Comment: I have added the response data in my question